# Custom tray panel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, system-tray, deskband

i need to create system tray "panel" like Windows Media Player. 
(not icon only, but complette form with buttons, images, etc.)

Here is wmp screenshot:

[image: wmp]

Is it possible in VB.NET & Win 10?

Thanks and sorry for my english.. :)

Comment: Your image doesn't work, but I suppose you're looking for a [**DeskBand**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx#desk_bands). Sadly it isn't very easy to do in .NET and requires P/Invoke knowledge.

Comment: THANKS! With this name ('DeskBand') i found documentation. :)

Answer (score -2):

You actually can do kind of a "tray panel", and it isn't quite difficult. Just create a `Form` Object and set its `FormBorderStyle` property to `None`, which will allow you to create your custom border. Then, do the following:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Timer1 As New Timer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as Eventargs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 1
    End Sub

     Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender as Object, e as MouseEventargs)
         Timer1.Start()
     End Sub

     Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender as Object, e as MouseEventargs)
         Timer1.Stop()
     End Sub

     Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender as Object, e as Eventargs)
         Me.Location = New Point(Me.Cursor.Position.X - (Me.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Location.X), Me.Cursor.Position.Y - (Me.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Location.Y))
     End Sub
End Class
```

Once you've done that (I'm not sure it will work directly, try a bit and it should), enjoy designing the GUI... ;-)

Hope this helps and by the way, your english is better than you think!

Comment: Umm... I guess the asker meant like embedding the whole thing on the taskbar, like a... see this image I found in Google: https://images.techhive.com/images/idge/imported/article/ctw/2012/06/06/lenovo_battery_charging_popupnote-100378724-orig.jpg Maybe the asker is asking for one like that...

Comment: Possible, however, I just thought my answer might have given him some help, I apologize in case it didn't!